# how to prove that there is an union of open intervals between a compact set and an open set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be a set of real numbers.
Let $U$ be the open set in $\mathbb{R}$, and $K$ be the compact set in $U$.
At this time, it seems to hold that
*there is some $\varepsilon > 0$, and for any $t \in K, (t-\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon) \subset U$.* 
But how can this be proven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $K \subseteq U$ and $U$ is open, for every $k \in K$ there is a $\varepsilon_k := d(x,U^{\complement})/2 > 0$ s.t. $(k - \varepsilon_k, k + \varepsilon_k) \cap U^{\complement} = \emptyset$. Here $d(k,U^{\complement}) = \inf_{u \in U^{\complement}}d(k,u)$ which is positive because $U$ is open.

Then define $\delta := \inf\{\varepsilon_k \vert k \in K\}$. Since $K$ is compact, $\delta>0$. There are multiple ways to see this:

Claim: $k \mapsto \varepsilon_k$ induces a continuous function $\phi: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via $k \mapsto d(k,U^{\complement})/2$.

Proof of claim: In fact, $k \mapsto d(k,U^{\complement})/2$ is even Lipschitz continuous. Let $x,y \in K$, then for every $u \in U^{\complement}$ we have

$$d(d(x,u), d(y,u)) = \vert d(x,u) - d(y,u)) \vert \leq d(x,y)$$

where we usethe definition of the metric in $\mathbb{R}$ in the first equality and the reverse triangle inequality in the second. Now take the infimum over all $u \in U^{\complement}$ on both sides and the result follows.

Since $K$ is compact $\phi$ attains a minimum which is by definition equal to $\delta$. Thats is, there exists a $k \in K$ s.t. $\varepsilon_k = \delta$ which is positive since $\varepsilon_k$ is positive.

This $\delta$ is now positive and has the property that for any $k \in K$ we have

$$(k - \delta, k + \delta) \subseteq (k - \varepsilon_k, k + \varepsilon_k) \subseteq U$$

The proof (and theorem) are valid in any metric space.

---

It is indeed crucial that $K$ is compact and not just closed. A counterexample to that would be $K = \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and $U = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}} (n - \frac{1}{n}, n + \frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: How can it be proven that $k \mapsto \varepsilon_k$ is continuous ?

Comment: I should have been more explicit there. I am currently editing.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the fact that for any $t \in K$ there is an $\epsilon_t$ such that $(t-\epsilon_t,t+\epsilon_t) \subseteq U$ and then try cover the compact set $K$ and take a finite subcover, at least from a first impression of the problem.